# Assigning DataContext to a public variable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datacontext

I'm messing with LINQ, and I'm trying to save lines of code. I created a variable in settings to indicate if I'm in Stage or Production, and I need to be able to switch between the two versions of the database for testing purposes. What I would *like* to do is create a function to handle my datacontext for me that I can just call when I want to create queries. Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
Public Class DataClass
Public env As String = My.Settings.Environ
Public prodDataString As String = My.Settings.ProdConnectionString
Public stageDataString As String = My.Settings.StageConnectionString
Public pConn As ProductionDataContext
Public sConn As StageDataContext

'To return my datacontext
Public Function conInit() As DataContext
        If env = "Production" Then
            Return pConn
        Else
            Return sConn
        End If
End Function

'To return my connection string
Public Function strInit() As String
        If env = "Production" Then
            Return prodDataString
        Else
            Return stageDataString
        End If
End Function

End Class
```

Now, in my function, I tried to set the DataContext to a variable like so:
Dim dConn As New DataContext(strInit())
I even tried using this:
dConn = conInit()

But it doesn't seem to take.
Suggestions?
I'm probably going about this all the wrong way, so if that's the case, any tips?
I know I can just put in every function

```
If env = "Production" Then 
  dim query = From r in pConn.table...
```

But I'd prefer not to.
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the connection string always have the same name and just be set to different environment values in the configuration?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you mean?
I have a connection string for the stage database and a connection string for production.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Comment: Ahhh, I store my connection strings in the application settings for ease of retrieval. For this project, the two that I have stored are ProdConnectionString and StageConnectionString.
See "To save a connection string directly into application settings": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx

Once they're set, I don't intend to change them. I'm using Environ to tell the program which one I want to use.

Comment: If it helps, what I basically want to do is to tell my class "For any function or sub procedure in this class, if I am x environment, I will use x datacontext for all my queries"